# Authentication Failed - Client to WCF to WCF Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, security, impersonation

I have a Windows Forms application which calls a "bussiness" WCF service. Let's call this one Business1. Business1 then calls Service1 - I want the credentials from the client to flow through Busines1 into Service1.

Currently I get an "authentication failed" from Busines1 - call doesn't even make it to the second service.

I've configured this service as follows:

Business 1 Config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://cdm/ecm/DocumentManagement.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="ConversantDocumentManagement" contract="ECM.IDocumentManagement" behaviorConfiguration="DelegationBehavior"
    name="ConversantDocumentManagement">
  </endpoint>
</client>
<services>
  <service name="Conversant.Applications.Services.Prosecution.ProsecutionService" behaviorConfiguration="ProsecutionServiceBehavior" >
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" name="ConversantProsecutionServiceEndpoint" contract="Conversant.Applications.Services.Prosecution.IProsecutionService" bindingConfiguration="ConversantProsecutionBinding"/>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ConversantProsecutionBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"  />
      </security>
    </binding>
      <binding name="ConversantDocumentManagement">
          <security mode="Message">
              <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"  />
          </security>
      </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
    <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ProsecutionServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceAuthorization impersonateCallerForAllOperations="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DelegationBehavior">
            <clientCredentials>
                <windows allowedImpersonationLevel="Delegation" allowNtlm="true" />
            </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
    <!--<add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    <add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="https"/>-->
</protocolMapping>    
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
```

Service1 Config:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="ECMServiceBehavior" name="Conversant.Applications.Services.ECM.Authentication">
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding_Authentication"
                name="ConversantDocumentManagement" contract="Conversant.Applications.Services.ECM.IAuthentication" >

            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="ECMServiceBehavior" name="Conversant.Applications.Services.ECM.DocumentManagement">
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding_DocumentManagement"
                name="ConversantDocumentManagement" contract="Conversant.Applications.Services.ECM.IDocumentManagement">

            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_DocumentManagement" receiveTimeout="00:05:00"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Authentication" />
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ContentService" messageEncoding="Mtom" />
            <binding name="ECMServer_NoAuth" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                transferMode="Streamed">
                <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
            <binding name="AuthenticationPortBinding" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <wsHttpBinding><binding name="wsHttpBinding_DocumentManagement" receiveTimeout="00:05:00"
                maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" >
                <security mode="Message">
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="wsHttpBinding_Authentication">
                <security mode="Message">
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ECMServiceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                <serviceAuthorization impersonateCallerForAllOperations="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="myBehavior">
                    <clientCredentials>
                        <windows allowedImpersonationLevel="Impersonation" allowNtlm="true"  />
                    </clientCredentials>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Finally for the sake of completion, the Windows Forms client (well, it's actually a unit test client for now - but same idea)

Client Config:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="ConversantProsecutionServiceEndpoint" openTimeout="00:03:00"
                receiveTimeout="00:05:00" sendTimeout="00:05:00">
                <security mode="Message">
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://cdm/prosecution/ProsecutionService.svc"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ConversantProsecutionServiceEndpoint"
            contract="ProsecutionService.IProsecutionService" name="ConversantProsecutionServiceEndpoint" behaviorConfiguration="DelegationBehavior">
        </endpoint>
    </client>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="DelegationBehavior">
                <clientCredentials>
                    <windows allowedImpersonationLevel="Delegation" allowNtlm="true" />
                </clientCredentials>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I want the call from Business1 to Service1 to be done under the currently logged in user.

domain\johndoe should be the user all the way through the calls.

Anyone have a link with an example of impersonation/delegation using WCF?

Thanks!

Comment: is it a multi hop request.. is the call going from one server (business1 server) to second server (server1) ?

Comment: Yes it is going from Business 1 to Service1. Both services are on the same server. I added an SPN record for HTTP/hostname (as well as FQDN) to the domain account running the applicationpool

Answer (score 0):

Where there is a multi hop request and you want to pass windows credentials from one server to another you have to set up the "Service Principal Names (SPN)" and "Delegate the request".

If you don't do that you cannot pass in the logged in user credentials in a multi-hop enviornment.

Comment: Yes it is going from Business 1 to Service1. Both services are on the same server. I added an SPN record for HTTP/hostname (as well as FQDN) to the domain account running the applicationpool